# Numbering proofs of theorem

Tags: theorems

I want to get something like (several proofs for single theorem):

```
Theorem 1. bla-bla-bla
Proof 1. bla-bla-bla
Proof 2. bla-bla-bla
Theorem 2. bla-bla-bla
Proof. bla-bla-bla
```

How I can reach it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You might define a  `numproof` environment, e.g. with the `ntheorem` package.

Comment: If you're using `amsthm` provided `proof` environment, then `\begin{proof}[Proof 1]` suffices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `amsthm` and its `proof` environment that accepts an optional argument for setting a nonstandard label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
This is a big statement that deserves two proofs.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}[\proofname\ 1]
This is the first proof.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}[\proofname\ 2]
This is the second proof.
\end{proof}

\begin{theorem}
This is a normal statement with a single proof.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
Exercise for the reader.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also type `\begin{proof}[Proof 1]`, of course. Using `\proofname` automaticall adapts to the language if `babel` is used.

If you, for some reasons, want to automatize the numbering, you can set up a counter that's reset when `theorem` is stepped up.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newcounter{proofs}[theorem]
\renewcommand{\theproofs}{\arabic{proofs}}

\newenvironment{numproof}
  {\stepcounter{proofs}\begin{proof}[\proofname\ \theproofs]}
  {\end{proof}}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
This is a big statement that deserves two proofs.
\end{theorem}

\begin{numproof}
This is the first proof.
\end{numproof}

\begin{numproof}
This is the second proof.
\end{numproof}

\begin{theorem}
This is another big statement with two proofs.
\end{theorem}

\begin{numproof}
This is the first proof.
\end{numproof}

\begin{numproof}
This is the second proof.
\end{numproof}

\end{document}
```

[image]